# Calculate each value of columns in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm new in excel programming. I need to calculate each value of columns in a cell, using corresponding row value as illustrated below:

[image]

How can I do it? 
I note that please do not answer me like: 
= POWER(A1, 2) 
= A1 ^ 2

I need some thing like: 
e(i) = POWER (A(i) ,2) 
In other words I need to set formula for each cell of column **E**, automatically.

Comment: In E1 enter `=A1^2`. Select the lower right corner of E1 and drag down.

Comment: @OldUgly This is not my answer. I need to set formula not 1 by 1. I need to set formula automatically.

Comment: you can select all cells that needs the formula in column E. Type your complete formula and press Ctrl+Enter

Comment: Sounds like you want a VBA solution. But filling column E with a simple formula is trivial and simpler.

Comment: your example shows only 1 column with a formula, what are you going to do with B:D? you need to make your question more descriptive - it's not clear what you need, and why using a formula approach would be "too much formula".  What do you mean by "automatic"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to suggest a solution based on understanding that you

1. need the formula to populate automatically
2. all it needs to do is to take power of 2 of the number in col A

My solution is based on turning your data into "excel Table" - if you're not aware, it's a special format which does a lot of work for you with formats, extending formulas automatically and does not require VBA.

1. Give your columns headers
2. select range, press Ctrl+T, in the pop up dialog, tick box "My Data has Headers" and OK.
3. This will turn your data into a blue-themed table
4. Type a name of column with formula in cell **E1**: i.e. Exp2 of Num1 (upper part of picture)
5. Create a formula in the first blank cell of the new column, hit Enter - the formula will drag itself down automatically
6. If you add more data to column A, column E (and any other columns with formulas you may add) will extend the formula automatically like in the bottom part of the picture

[image: PICTURE FOR STEP 5 creating formula after table has been made]

*N.B. when you type the formula, and select a cell in col A, the table picks up it's Column name - as highlighted in upper picture. You can use A2 reference as well though*

and this is what happens if you simply copy-paste data into column 1 - watch col E, that was automatic:

[image: ADDED NEW DATA IN COL A]

you can add more columns to the table and the same will happen - any formats/formulas in columns are preserved if you add more data.

Apologies if you already knew that.

**P.S. please remember to mark as Answer if any of the people who took time to answer, provided a helpful solution that's fair to the context you provided**

Answer (score 0):

User `=Power(Number,Power)` function.

```
=POWER(A1,2)
```

You can also use below formula

```
=A1^2
```

Comment: No, by this approach I should a lot formula for each cell!

Comment: @Babak.Abad Then you have to use `VBA` macro to do that.